# MongoDB Aggregation PHP, Group by Hours

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have documents with the following format

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("12e123123123123123"),
  "client_id" : "12345667889",
  "resource" : "test/test",
  "version" : "v2",
  "ts" : new Date("Wed, 02 Jan 2013 15:34:58 GMT +08:00")
}
```

The `ts` is a MongoDate() field.

I am trying to use MongoDB aggregate function in php to group by client_id and hour and count usage to display in a table/graph

This is my current attempt

```
$usage = $this->db->Usage->aggregate(array(array(
  '$project' => array(
    'hour' => array(
      'years' => array( '$year' => '$ts' ),
      'months' => array( '$month' => '$ts' ),
      'days' => array( '$dayOfMonth' => '$ts' ),
      'hours' => array( '$hour' => '$ts' ),
    )
  ),
  '$group' => array(
    '_id' => array(
      'client_id' => '$client_id',
      'hour' => '$hour',
    ),
   'number' => array('$sum' => 1),
  )
)));
```

Unfortunately my response I am getting back is just grouping by the client_id and nothing else.

```
[result] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [_id] => Array
                    (
                        [client_id] => adacf8deba7066e4
                    )

                [number] => 12
            )

    )
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction, or have another solution to group by hour?

--Fixed--
PHP requires that you put each pipeline in a separate array as well as putting the whole thing in an array. see update solution below with help from JohnnyHK

```
$usage = $this->db->Usage->aggregate(array(array(
        '$project' => array(
            'client_id' => 1,
            'hour' => array(
                'years' => array( '$year' => '$ts' ),
                'months' => array( '$month' => '$ts' ),
                'days' => array( '$dayOfMonth' => '$ts' ),
                'hours' => array( '$hour' => '$ts' ),
            )
        )),array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                'client_id' => '$client_id',
                'hour' => '$hour',
            ),
            'number' => array('$sum' => 1),
        )
    )));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't create the results you're seeing, but you do need to include `client_id` in your `$project` operator so that it's available to the `$group` operator.

```
'$project' => array(
  'client_id' => 1,
  'hour' => array(
    'years' => array( '$year' => '$ts' ),
    'months' => array( '$month' => '$ts' ),
    'days' => array( '$dayOfMonth' => '$ts' ),
    'hours' => array( '$hour' => '$ts' ),
  )
),
```

The shell equivalent worked after I made that change:

```js
db.test.aggregate(
    { $project: {
        hour: {
            years: {$year: '$ts'},
            months: {$month: '$ts'},
            days: {$dayOfMonth: '$ts'},
            hours: {$hour: '$ts'}
        },
        client_id: '$client_id'
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: { client_id: '$client_id', hour: '$hour' },
        number: { $sum: 1}
    }})
```

returned:

```js
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "client_id": "12345667889",
        "hour": {
          "years": 2013,
          "months": 1,
          "days": 2,
          "hours": 7
        }
      },
      "number": 1
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same response. I tried the same in the shell and am getting back the same wrong result, which makes me think it has something to do with either the way my Collection is setup or Mongodb itself. I'm running version 2.2.2.

Comment: Strange.  I added the shell equivalent I was using to test this with MongoDB v2.2.2.

Comment: Awesome fixed it. It was the way php required to pass through the variables. Adding the client_id was needed in the project though. I will update my question with the solution.