# Get count for each day in mongodb using aggregate or map reduce

Tags: mysql, mongodb

How do i convert the below mysql query to mongodb query:   `SELECT count(*) as count ,  DATE_FORMAT( timestamp, '%d-%c-%Y' ) as day,  timestamp as tm FROM visits WHERE 1 GROUP BY day ORDER BY tm`. I want to use this on a nodejs so i am using native mongodb.

Get the number of pageviews for each day in mongodb where each pageview is stored along with the timestamp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question lacks any effort on your part and we rarely just "give" people the answer like this, however, this one time:

**NB**: you cannot yet manipulate dates to cast them to different formats without some manual work yourself of picking the parts out and rejoining them. Because of this I have left out the date formatting you did and just used it as an object.

```
db.visits.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            date: {day: {$dayOfMonth: '$timestamp'}, month: {$month: '$timestamp'}, year: {$year: '$timestamp'}},
            //day: {concat: [date.day,date.mont,date.year]}
        }
    },
    {$group: {_id: '$date', tm: '$timestamp', count: {$sum:1}}}
])
```

Comment: Hey congrats on 10K+ reps :)

Comment: I get the ERROR: MongoError: exception: the group aggregate field 'tm' must be defined as
 an expression inside an object

Comment: @peter weird I don't get that

Comment: The below query seems to work perfectly for me:       db.visits.aggregate(
    { $project: {
        day: { 
   years: {$year: '$timestamp'},
   months: {$month: '$timestamp'},
   days: {$dayOfMonth: '$timestamp'},
        },
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: { day: '$day' },
        count: { $sum: 1}
    }},{ $sort:{_id:1}}); Got the answer from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120123/mongodb-aggregation-php-group-by-hours)

Comment: @peter It would be better to try and put the sort at the beginning and use `$first` or `$last` to get the first or last of the sorted set otherwise the sort will be in-memory and not index based, hmm but you can't avoid that

Comment: @Sammaye I needed to get all the entries and not only the last or the first one. My above query seems to be working perfectly for my requirement, thanks anyways

Comment: @peter indeed it will work, it might just be slow under some occasions :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a working mongodb query using mapreduce which gives me the output time as unix time rather than the format I had mentioned in the question. But this was the query that was sorting the time properly. I had tried mongo group query but it did not sort according to time. The working mongo query is :

```
db.visits.mapReduce(
function(){
  day = Date.UTC(this.timestamp.getFullYear(), this.timestamp.getMonth(), this.timestamp.getDate());

  emit({day: day}, {count: 1});
}, 
function(key, values) {
  var count = 0;

  values.forEach(function(v) {
    count += v['count'];
  });

  return {count: count};
},
             {
              out : {inline:1},
              sort:{_id:1}
             }
);
```