# MongoDB aggregation by time interval PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, highcharts, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB to store server statistics that are captured every 15 seconds (so 4 rows get inserted each minute per server) and am trying to get this data plotted onto a graph for all data between a certain timestamp.

For example, the following query can be used:

```
$tbl->find(
  array(
    "timestamp" => array('$gte' => '1396310400', '$lte' => '1396915200'), 
    "service" => 'a715feac3db42f54edbc50ef6fa057b3'
  ),
  array("timestamp" => 1, "system" => 1)
);
```

Which spits our a bunch of rows that look like this:

```
Array
(
    [53933ad8532965621d97dd3b] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoId Object
                (
                    [$id] => 53933ad8532965621d97dd3b
                )

            [system] => Array
                (
                    [load] => 0.55
                    [uptime] => 1171204.47
                    [processes] => 222
                )

            [timestamp] => 1396310403
        )

)
```

This works fine for small data ranges, as I can pass this data directly into Flot or HighCharts and let it prettify the time scales itself. However this doesn't work for large data sets (for example querying over a month).

What I'm trying to do is group the data by hour (or 15 minutes), and return the average values (in this example, its system.load that I'm plotting) for that given time period.

I know that the aggregate function is what I need be using, but despite my best efforts I've been unable to get this working.

Right now I'm letting PHP do all of the work (grouping the results by timestamp and working out the averages) but it's extremely slow and I know MongoDB would handle it better.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I've been trying to follow the answer posted here but am still struggling - [MongoDB Aggregation PHP, Group by Hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120123/mongodb-aggregation-php-group-by-hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at your initial query at the top of your question and it immediately tells me that your "timestamp" values are actually strings. So no doubt that when you are reading this information and doing your "manual aggregation" you are actually casting these values, and possibly others into types that you can manipulate, sum and average.

So the first part here is to fix your data, that looks like it has come from a logging source but you have never converted the values. I'm considering it reasonably possible that this is not just the timestamp values but probably also your metrics under system.

This leaves you with a choice of how to store your timestamp. You can either just keep that as  a timestamp number as it currently is in string form, or you can opt for converting to a [BSON date type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date). The first one will be a simple integer cast and save back, the other you should be able to feed to the `Date` type that is supported by the driver and again save back the data.

When you have done this, then you can happily use the aggregation functions. So as an example for if you choose to keep this as a number, then you just apply date math in order to get the grouping boundaries:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

   // Match documents on the range you want
   { "$match": {
       "timestamp": {
           "$gte": 1396310400, "$lte": 1396915200
       },
       "service": "a715feac3db42f54edbc50ef6fa057b3"
   }},

   // Group on the time intervals, 15 minutes here
   { "$group": {
       "_id": { 
           "service": "$service",
           "time": {
               "$subtract": [
                   "$timestamp",
                   { "$mod": [ "$timestamp", 60 * 15 ] }
               ]
           }
       },
       "load": { "$avg": "$system.load" }
   }},

   // Project to the output form you want
   { "$project": {      
       "service": "$_id.service",
       "time" : "$_id.time",
       "load": 1
   }}
])
```

Or to be php specific

```php
$tbl->aggregate(array(
    array(      
        '$match' => array(
            'timestamp' => array(
                '$gte' => 1396310400, '$lte' => 1396915200
            ),
            'service' => 'a715feac3db42f54edbc50ef6fa057b3'
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                'service' => '$service',
                'time' => array(
                    '$subtract' => array(
                       '$timestamp',
                       array( '$mod' => array('$timestamp', 60 * 15 ) )
                    )
                )
            ),
            'load' => array( '$avg' => '$system.load' )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            'service' => '$_id.service',
            'time' => '$_id.time',
            'load' => 1
        )
    )
))
```

Otherwise if you choose to convert to BSON dates then you can use the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) instead:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$match": {
       "timestamp": {
           "$gte": new Date("2014-04-01"), "$lte": new Date("2014-04-08")
       },
       "service": "a715feac3db42f54edbc50ef6fa057b3"
   }},
   { "$group": {
       "service": "$service",
       "time": {
           "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$timestamp" },
           "hour": { "$hour": "$timestamp" },
           "minute": {
               "$subtract": [
                   { "$minute": "$timestamp" },
                   { 
                       "$mod": [
                           { "$minute": "$timestamp" },
                           15
                       ]
                   }
               ]
           }
       },
       "load": { "$avg": "$system.load" }
   }},
   { "$project": {
       "service": "$_id.service",
       "time": "$_id.time",
       "load": 1
   }}
])
```

So there you have the help of the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) to break up parts of the date your have and still use the same modulo operation in order to get interval values.

If you still prefer the date math approach you can still do this with date objects as the result of subtracting one date object from another will be the epoch timestamp value. So moving a BSON date to a epoch timestamp is just a matter of:

```
{
    "$subtract": [
        "$dateObjectField",
        new Date("1970-01-01")
    ]
}
```

So any "date" values you pass in to the pipeline here you can cast using the native type methods of your driver and it will be serialized correctly when the request is sent to MongoDB. The other advantage is the same is true when you read them back, so there is no more need for conversion in client processing.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the comprehensive answer. I'll get this implemented in the next 20 minutes or so and will report back.

I am looking to change the timestamp fields to the BSON native format, I just haven't figured the best way to do this yet.

Comment: Your answer worked flawlessly, I just had to to correct the `:` in
`array( '$mod': array('$timestamp', 60 * 15 ) )`

Right now, the data is stored in MySQL and so for my test data I've wrote a script that selects batches of data at a time from MySQL and inserts the rows into MongoDB. It may be out of the scope of this question, but is there anything specific I need to do to convert my current timestamp format (unix timestamp) to Mongo's usable format?

Comment: @LeeBrooks There is documentation for the MongoDB driver including the [MongoDate](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.mongodate.php) class

Comment: Aye, I've just read up on this and got everything running smoothly; I can't thank you enough :)